# From each filepath in each line extract filename and add next to it

Tags: vim

Given my text in a file:

```
/home/dir1/file1.txt
/home/dir2/file2.txt
...
/home/dirn/filek.txt
```

I would like it to be this text instead:

```
/home/dir1/file1.txt file1
/home/dir2/file2.txt file2
...
/home/dirn/filek.txt filek
```

Can I write this in vim?

Comment: You might want to consider the [Vi & Vim StackExchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com) for questions on Vim.

Comment: Will do that from next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex works:

```
:%s#.*/\(.*\)\.txt$#& \1#
```

The starting `.*/` skips everything until the last slash (it's greedy, so it will catch all the directory part.)

Then we capture the filename in a group with `\(.*\)`.

And finally we match the extension with `\.txt` and anchor it to the end of the line.

For the replacement, we use a `&` to keep the full path around and then add `\1` to include the filename only.

We can use `#` as a delimiter, so we don't need to escape the `/`s. We only have one here, but that's an useful technique to use when paths are involved, so I'm making sure I use it here for consistency.

You might want to take a look at [`:help pattern-searches`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html) to learn more about Vim regexes you can use for search and substitutions.

(In general, the Vim documentation is great and the help system can be very useful if you know how to navigate it, see [`:help helphelp`](https://vimhelp.org/helphelp.txt.html) for more.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will follow it. Again cheers for the explanation.